# Web.config for HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, https, web-config

I am struggling to setup my web.config for my .NET web-service. It is supposed to accept both HTTP and HTTPS requests (HTTP only for legacy version of the client software).

I am not a web-developer so all of this is pretty much new for me.

This is the web-config that I had so far, which worked fine for HTTP only. But now I need to add HTTPS support for it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help is highly appreciated as I don't even know where to start.

I tried changing the serviceMetadata to

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

but that just left me with neither HTTP nor HTTPS working

Comment: `<system.serviceModel>` is for WCF - dare I ask what happened?

Comment: I would love to answer if I would understand the question